# Facebook API Auto-Generate OAuth Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Say that I have a website where I'd like to pull public data from a certain fan base on Facebook (i.e. recent posts, likes, places, etc.), but do not want a viewer to have to sign into FB. Understand that I wouldn't be interested in any particular user's information, and thus wouldn't need their specific login authentication. Is there a way to auto-generate an OAuth token to use with the FB API so that generic requests could be made without forcing the user to login?

Comment: What about using an application access token? You can still get some public information with it.

Comment: From what I've read, it seems that most wrappers for the FB SDK require both the FB App ID and also an OAuth token passed in to make requests. Am I wrong?

Comment: Those same SDK's will usually allow you to manually specify an access token for a session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use an application access token to make these calls. To create you app access token, simply concatenate your `APP_ID` and your `APP_SECRET` with a pipe character.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/feed?access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET
```

This will return all the public stories from the Facebook developers page feed. You can use the pages vanity URL if it has one, but you can also use the `PAGE_ID`.

Comment: Beautiful. Can I also get information about likes, comments, etc. on public pages?

Comment: A request to /FacebookDevelopers will give you some general information including a "like count". The feed itself will contain comments on posts.. if not, you can always query that post and get it's comments (using the same token).

Comment: You can try all this out using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)